# Gmail login automation code stuck at email field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate gmail login page.
The following steps are to be automated :
Step 1. Go to Google.com
Step 2. Search for gmail
Step 3. Click on Gmail
Step 4. Verify you are on gmail site
Step 5. Enter username
Step 6. Click on next
Step 7. Enter password
Step 8. Click on Sign In
Step 9. Verify you get a new page
Step 10.Click on Compose button

But the  code gets stuck on the email field. The cursor keeps blinking on the email field.

Here is the code:

```
package com.google.mail;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class OpenGmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Chandra\\Desktop\\SELENIUM\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/a[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='initialView']/div[1]"));
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("headingText")));
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("headingSubtext")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xxxxxkmr51");
        driver.findElement(By.className("RveJvd snByac")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("whsOnd zHQkBf")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.className("RveJvd snByac")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':j3']/div/div")).click();
       }
}
```

And here is the error code :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='initialView']/div[2]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'CXxXXXX-PC', ip: '192.168.1.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:10057/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, platform=XP}]
Session ID: 99e8cbc9-b603-49b9-8cd2-de4f4a8da7f5
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='initialView']/div[2]}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:416)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:408)
    at com.google.mail.OpenGmail.main(OpenGmail.java:16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

and you can go directly to login page from [here](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?)
this will make it faster and avoid unnecessary steps

```
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("password"))); 
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct +10. IF my answer is correct Please upvote

Answer (score 2):

According to error code, your test fails on this step:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='initialView']/div[1]"));
```

Please remove it I think that You don't need it. Other should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/")
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']")).click();

WebDriverWait waitforPwd= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
waitforPwd.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("password")); 
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwordNext']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi below code should work for you :


package com.google.mail;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Mytestclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\Chandra\\Desktop\\SELENIUM\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");


        driver.get("https://https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Next']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Next']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- I advace you should work with Firefox. So, there is a some add-on for test development in FF. Such as "selenium ide". It logs each step after that you can get export to your code. Search it.

2-Other add-on is "Selenium Page Object Generator" you can find all elements xpath,css,classname. So, you do not mistake for any locator. Search it!

3- your code's 6.th line in main method. What do you want it?
"driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='initialView']/div[1]"));" There is no any action like click, send key or anything else. You can this code.

```html
public class GmailTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://www.google.com.tr/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGmailscript() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("gmail");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(600);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']/div/div/div/div/div/h3/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierId")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#identifierId")).sendKeys("yourmail@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']/div[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(600);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwordNext']/div[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(600);
        //control for gmail page is open or not. I used "write e-mail" element for control.
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':io']/div/div")).isEnabled(),"Page is not open");
        System.out.println("Page is open");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
            driver.switchTo().alert();
            return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String alertText = alert.getText();
            if (acceptNextAlert) {
                alert.accept();
            } else {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        } finally {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
}
```